# Remove route param from url AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I want to remove route param from url.

My urls can be *http://host.domain/#/events/eventId* and *http://host.domain/#/user/userId/events/eventId*
My $routeProvider is set as *'/events/:eventId?'* and *'user/:userId/events/:eventId?'*

When **eventId** is set I show popup. When user click close button, I want to remove eventId from url. How I can do this?

p.s. I was looking for something like this

```
delete $route.current.params.eventId;
```

but without any success

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `delete`. The keyword is used to delete properties from JavaScript objects.

Typically, people just either add a button like this:

```
<button ui-sref="events()">Close</button>
```

or they use `$state.go` command:

```
$state.go("events", { });
```

in these kind of situations where `events` is your route without `eventId` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you look into [UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/). It is far more versatile than ngRoute and offers everything the aforementioned module does.

Using that, you could define a separate state to go to when there's no **eventId**.

```
.state("mystate", {
   url: "/",
   template: "..."
})
.state("mystate.event", {
   url: "/:eventId",
   template: "..."
   ...
});
```

A URL like "**/321**" would match the state **mystate.event**, while "**/**" would resolve to **mystate**. 
If you want to click on something and go from one state to the other, you can use **ui-sref**.

To go to a state without any params:

```
ui-sref="targetState";
```

To go to a state with params:

```
ui-sref="targetState({ paramName: param });
```

In your case, you could have something like:

```
<div ui-sref="mystate">Click to Close</div>
```

And that's all there'd be to it. [This tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) covers the basics of what you need to get started with UI-Router, and you can also find tips and tricks on the same topic on the same site.

**EDIT**

You can also do it the way described in Martin's answer.